# A method to add an object to an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Hello I have an assignment which I should create a Person class and write necessary codes for it. This could be so easy if i could use some kind of `List`
however, we are not allowed to use `List` . That's why I am using only arrays. So i could write some codes but I'm stuck on `allCousins()` and `allAncestors()` methods. I tried everything i could find on internet and some answers here helped me a lot but still, I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. So if you could help me on that, I'd be so appreciated.

In my assignment we have to write some methods like `allBrothers()`, `allSiblings()`I wrote these ones and they work. Here is an example code of allSiblings():

```
public Person[] allSiblings(){
        Person[] siblings = new Person[0];
        for(int i=0;i<this.mother.children.length;i++){
            if(this.mother.children[i]==this)
                continue;
            else{
                Person[] newArray = new Person[siblings.length+1];
                System.arraycopy(siblings, 0, newArray, 0, siblings.length);
                newArray[newArray.length-1] = this.mother.children[i];
                siblings = newArray;
            }
        }
    return siblings;
}
```

And there is this allCousins() method which returns an array of Person objects. here is what i tried so far but couldn't manage it to work.

```
public Person[] allCousins(){
        Person[] cousins = new Person[0];
        for(int i = 0;i<this.getParents().length;i++){
            for(int a = 0;a<this.getParents()[i].allSiblings().length;i++){
                cousins = combine(cousins, this.getParents()[i].allSiblings()[a].getChildren())
            }   
        }
        return cousins;
    }

public static Person[] combine(Person[] a, Person[] b){
        int length = a.length + b.length;
        Person[] result = new Person[length];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
        return result;
    }
```

Here i tried to add every uncle's and aunt's children array to cousins array and return it but didn't work. Then i tried to do it child by child. But that didn't work also. Here is the code, I know it's a stupid way to do it and unnecessarily complicated

```
public Person[] allCousins(){
        Person[] cousins = new Person[0];
        for(int i = 0;i<this.father.allSiblings().length;i++){
            for(int a = 0;i<this.father.allSiblings()[i].allChildren().length;a++){
                Person[] newArray = new Person[cousins.length+1];
                System.arraycopy(cousins, 0, newArray, 0, cousins.length);
                newArray[newArray.length-1] = this.father.allSiblings()[i].allChildren()[a];
                cousins = newArray;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<this.mother.allSiblings().length;i++){
            for(int a = 0;i<this.mother.allSiblings()[i].allChildren().length;a++){
                Person[] newArray = new Person[cousins.length+1];
                System.arraycopy(cousins, 0, newArray, 0, cousins.length);
                newArray[newArray.length-1] = this.mother.allSiblings()[i].allChildren()[a];
                cousins = newArray;
            }
        }
        return cousins;
    }
```

I couldn't find where the problem is because `allSiblings()` and `allChildren()` works and these are the only methods i used in examples above. Probably i am missing something in for loops because it gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but i can't find it. So if you can help me, I'd be so glad.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your entire exception including full stack trace.

Comment: i don't know how to do that.

Comment: If you are permitted to use [foreach statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), you should do so.  Your code will become dramatically simpler and this problem will cease to be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

The indexes are wrong in your `for` loops. For the first `allCousins()`:

```
for(int a = 0;a<this.getParents()[i].allSiblings().length;i++){
                                                          ^
                                                          should be a++
```

And for the second `allCousins()` (for mother and father loops):

```
for(int a = 0;i<this.father.allSiblings()[i].allChildren().length;a++){
              ^
              should be a
```

Answer (score 0):

When I am troubleshooting, I create variables to hold variables that are part of control statements. You have

```
for(int i = 0;i<this.father.allSiblings().length;i++){ ... }
```

I suggest this:

```
Person[] dadsSiblings = this.father.allSiblings();
int numberOfDadsSibs = dadsSiblings.length;
for(int i = 0;i<numberOfDadsSibs ;i++){...}
```

and so on. Then, when you have got everything working, you can get rid of such variables if necessary. If you use a debugger, you can set breakpoints to look at those those variables to make sure that they have the values you expect. If you don't use a debugger, print the values to the console to make sure that they have the right values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that instead of

```
       for(int a = 0; i < this.father.allSiblings()[i].allChildren().length; a++)
```

you should have

```
       for(int a = 0; a < this.father.allSiblings()[i].allChildren().length; a++)
```

otherwise you `a` can grow uncontrollably and at some point exceed the length of the array.